# Syntax for Nested Excel Formula - SUMIF Where the Sum Range is a VLOOKUP Which has a Concatenation of Text and Cell Values to Makeup a Sheet Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, syntax

I have a interesting puzzle going on which I believe is a syntax issue that has to do with the nesting of the formula in question.  The reason I'm using such a funky formula is probably longwinded to the point of not being interesting, and certainly not useful to solving the issue I'm having.  It would be possible to solve my issue without this formula but it would require a VBA project which isn't ideal for this use case.  The formula is as follows:

```
=SUMIF('Sheet1'!$BR:$BR,'Sheet2'!$C19,CONCAT("'Sheet1'!",VLOOKUP(CONCAT($B$1," ",F$5),'Sheet3'!$J:$P,7,FALSE)))
```

Pulling the full formula apart, I have two formulas that work as expected:

Piece One:  `=SUMIF('Sheet1'!$BR:$BR,'Sheet2'!$C19,'Sheet1!'$AV:$AV)`

Piece Two:  `=CONCAT("'Sheet1'!",VLOOKUP(CONCAT($B$1," ",F$5),'Sheet3'!$J:$P,7,FALSE))`

Piece Two returns a value of `'Sheet1'!AV:AV` and Piece One returns a value of `1,000,000` which is the correct SUMIF for the criteria I've set up in the formula.  I've tried all sorts of combinations of `(` and `)` but continue to have Excel give me the message of either `Your formula is missing a open or close parenthesis` or `Did you mean for this to be a formula?  When starting a cell with a = or -....`.

I'm trying to get the nested formula to resolve the "Part Two" first, so that when the entire nested formula evaluates it would solve "Part Two" which would leave me with an identical formula to "Part One" which would result in the 1,000,000 answer.

What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance - this one's got me stumped!

Comment: If you'd change your values on sheet3 to actual indices, you got yourself the possibility to write a semi-volatile function. Something along the lines of: `=SUMIF(Sheet1!$BR:$BR,Sheet2!$C19,INDEX(Sheet1!1:1048576,,VLOOKUP(CONCAT($B$1," ",F$5),Sheet3!$J:$P,7,0)))`

Comment: @JvdV As far as I know that's not volatile at all. Even as a worse case, when, for example, using `INDEX` in the form `A1:INDEX()`, "semi-volatile" would be a bit harsh, since it's technically only volatile once, i.e. at workbook open.

Comment: @JosWoolley, that's how I also understood the semi-volatile. However, I call it semi-volatile since when I do call it non-volatile I do get corrected by someone else (who is then technically right) =). In this case however, there is no setback at all, since SUMIF() itself is semi-volatile and will recalculate on workbook-open.

Comment: @JvdV Do you have a reference for that statement re `SUMIF`? I know that `SUMIF` is fully volatile when the *range* and *sum_range* parameters are of unequal dimensions, though I've never heard of it being semi-volatile in its standard form.

Comment: @JosWoolley, [here](https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2019/jun/microsoft-excel-volatile-functions-201920646.html) is one.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, but that's just as I said, i.e. only "*becomes volatile whenever the size of the first range argument is not the same as the second (sum_range) argument*". And not many users employ that function in such a way, to be honest.

Comment: @JosWolley, I've not done anything *but* same-sized range arguments all my Excel-life tbh. And to be completely honest, I had actually never known about this volatile option to simply reference a single cell in the 3rd parameter. Quite the eye-opener there (and a dangerous one if not aware).

Comment: @JvdV Yeah, I've personally only ever used it for 'shortest-formula challenges' to save a couple of characters! Kind of strange that MS allow such a syntax with implicit intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Excel will not by default interpret your string as a range reference. You need to pass it to `INDIRECT` so as to be interpreted as such:

```
=SUMIF(
    Sheet1!$BR:$BR,
    Sheet2!$C19,
    INDIRECT(
        CONCAT("'Sheet1'!", VLOOKUP(CONCAT($B$1, " ", F$5), Sheet3!$J:$P, 7, FALSE))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Piece Two returns a value of 'Sheet1'!$AV:$AV

Piece Two in this case returns a string value, that happens to *say* 'Sheet1'!$AV:$AV. What you need piece two to return is not a text string, but a reference (or 'link') to the range on the sheet that is *called* 'Sheet1'!$AV:$AV.

To convert a string to a range reference you use the `INDIRECT()` function.

So your new formula is

```
SUMIF('Sheet1'!$BR:$BR,'Sheet2'!$C19,INDIRECT(CONCAT("'Sheet1'!",VLOOKUP(CONCAT($B$1," ",F$5),'Sheet3'!$J:$P,7,FALSE))))
```